# Does INFORMATION_SCHEMA always contain up-to-date metadata?

Tags: mysql, information-schema, database-size

This query prints the size (in terms of data and indexes) of the tables in *mydatabase*:

```
SELECT table_name "Table name", 
round(((data_length)/1024/1024),2) "Data size",
round(((index_length)/1024/1024),2) "Index size" 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE table_schema="mydatabase" AND data_length>1000000 
order by table_name INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/mydatabase_values' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Sizes are printed in Mb, and only tables larger than 1Mb are considered. Tables are listed in alphabetical order and the output is saved into a CSV file.

Running this query at different points in time showed - obviously - different results as data changed in the database.  However, just in the last few weeks the query produced identical results.  Does it mean that the database hasn't changed much in size (as you can see, rounding is done at the 10Kb boundary) or is there something I am really missing?  The question might sound absurd, but do the views in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` always hold up-to-date metadata?

Note: no, I am not reading each time the same CSV file by mistake.

Edit: all tables are InnoDB, and `innodb_file_per_table=1`.

Comment: Did you maybe delete some bigger numbers of rows? Do you use `innodb_file_per_table = 1` (and are the tables InnoDB or MyISAM)? MySQL won't shrink the files after deletes (without alter/optimize) but instead later reuses the space without growing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's `innodb_file_per_table=1` (I've added this to the question) and all tables are InnoDB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the data is up-to-date.  But don't read too much into the numbers.

InnoDB, especially, preallocates space for future rows.  So, it is quite possible to look at the exact size of a table, insert dozens of rows (maybe even thousands), then look at the size again -- and see exactly the same Data_length and Index_length.

When you *first* create an InnoDB table and insert one small row, the data length will be 16384 bytes (one 16KB block).  As you add more rows, *eventually* that block will overflow, and another block will be added.  Later (as the table exceeds some threshold), the table will grow in units of (I think) 8MB (an "extent").  This will allow even more rows to be added with *no* change in disk footprint.

Also, was the table created with `innodb_file_per_table` ON or OFF?  This controls whether the stuff goes into the communal `ibdata1` file or the table's own `.ibd` file.

And, as @jkavalik points out, `DELETE` and `UPDATE` and `ALTER` can mess with the size, again not necessarily in predictable ways.

**Edit**

Those are the "disk footprint" size.  Compare to what you can see looking at the filesystem.

A 1-row table with one 4-byte `INT` takes at least 16384 bytes of disk space.  If you are saying that "4" is the *real* size, then I have been answering the wrong question.  I say that 16KB is the *real* size.

There is overhead for each column, for each row, for each block, for BTree structure, for each extent, for indexes, etc.  And InnoDB allocates no less than 16KB at a time.  And room for 'undo' copies of rows.  Hence, "4" turns into "16384".

As a "Rule of Thumb", if you add up the data sizes (4 for INT, etc) of the columns in a row, multiply by the number of rows, then multiply by something between 2 and 3, you are likely to get the "size" of the table.  (The 1-col, 1-row example, of course, is an end-case that exceeds 3x)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's `innodb_file_per_table=1` (I've added this to the question). Do you suggest any way to get the *real* table sizes -- perhaps running OPTIMIZE beforehand?

Comment: (See Edit that I added to the Answer.)  `OPTIMIZE` _might_ shrink _some_ of the fluff out of the allocation.  But you will _still_ see a factor of 2x-3x "overhead".  Almost never is it advisable to do routine `OPTIMIZE` on InnoDB tables.  Try it.  Perhaps you will see what I mean.  (Or you will hit one of _many_ exceptions that further confuses the issue.)

Comment: Yes, I know what you mean. I wasn't really keen to do an OPTIMIZE before every report (although many see it as a panacea for any database problem). Good thing you confirmed my doubts.